# 3 Attempts to delete XML node using C#

Tags: c#, sql, xml, linq-to-xml

I've tried deleting a node from my XML file 3 different ways; and each way I've come up empty. I am querying a SQL database and grabbing a filename, I want to delete the entire node were the file name in the XML document is = to the SQL database result.

I'm not sure what's wrong in my code:

Background Information

> fn44 is the Filename grabbed from a SQL database (all my info is in a
>   SQL table, I need an XML file for use with JavaScript)

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
  <bannerMain>
    <department>main</department>
    <filename>resdrop.png</filename>
    <title>This is a Title</title>
    <text>&lt;![CDATA[caption <a href="">text</a>]]&gt;</text>
  </bannerMain>
</xml>
```

Attempt 1 (I know that I'm not getting to the child correctly, can't seem to figure out how to fix it):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/banners.xml"));
var q = from node in doc.Descendants("bannerMain")
        let fina = node.Descendants("filename")/*PROBLEM LINE*/
        where fina != null && fina == myReader[0]/*Gets filename from SQL database*/
select node;
q.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/banners.xml"));
```

Attempt 2 (should work in my mind but doesn't)

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/banners.xml"));
XmlNode nodeToDelete = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/xml/bannerMain[@filename=" 
+ fn44 + "]");
if (nodeToDelete != null)
{
   nodeToDelete.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodeToDelete);
}
xmlDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/banners.xml"));
```

Attempt 3 (similar to attempt 2)

```
string nodeToDelete = fn44;
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/banners.xml"));
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//*[filename=\"{0}\"]"
, nodeToDelete));
if (node != null)
   xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("xml/bannersMain").RemoveChild(node);
xmlDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/banners.xml"));
```

I want to delete the whole node where the filename is = to the filename that is grabbed from the SQL database. Any help/resources is much appreciated.

**SOLVED:**
There's a few different options in the below answers that work out well.

Solution 1:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/banners.xml"));
string fileName = fn44; //Use whatever value you found in SQL DB...

xDoc.Descendants("filename").Where(c => c.Value == fileName).Select(x => x.Parent).Remove();
xDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/banners.xml"));
```

Solution 2:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/banners.xml"));
var q = from node in doc.Descendants("bannerMain")
        let fina = node.Element("filename")
        where fina != null && fina.Value == fn44
        select node;
q.Remove();
doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/banners.xml"));
```

Comment: Why not start from an XML template with no filenames and add all of them except the one you found in the database ? Does that make sense ?

Comment: The xml nodes are created during the upload process of a new file. Both SQL and XML information are generated at this time. This process I have running when I am trying to delete an entry. Thus deleting the file from the server, from the xml document, as well as the SQL database. I have the server and SQL delete working; the xml delete is proving to be difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems to work for me:

```
        string xmlfile = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/banners.xml");
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlfile);
        string fileName = "resdrop.png"; // Value from SQL DB

        xDoc.Descendants("filename")
            .Where(c => c.Value == fileName)
            .Select(x => x.Parent)
            .Remove();
        xDoc.Save(xmlfile);
```

Comment: If you look at his code Francis, you will see he doesn't want to remove all the filename nodes, but the parent banner node where it has a child filename that matches his search.  I'd modify your approach with a `.Select(f => f.Parent).Remove()`

Comment: Right, missed the "entire node" mention. Thanks for mentionning.

Comment: You might also specify just filename nodes in your `Descendants` with `Descendants("filename")` to be sure that some other node doesn't match the search by accident.

Comment: Now you are removing all the nodes that have filename, not checking to see if it matches the filename he is looking for.  If you don't mind, I can edit your answer if you are confused.

Comment: Would I do something like xDoc.Descendants("filename="+fileName+"]").Select(x => x.Parent).Remove();

Comment: Done. Sorry if I look so confused. :P

Comment: @Jobokai Look at my last edit, you will see where to use the value you found in SQL.

Comment: @Jobokai No, because in `Descendants` you are looking for node names, not the value of the nodes.

Comment: It's working! Went ahead and accepted this answer. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Cleaned up code so future viewers don't have to use the scrollbar to see the code.  Good answer!

Comment: I editted it to include the Server.MapPath function. It's a little bit better than doing hard coded absolute paths. In case your files get moved to a different location and the path changes, everything would still work.

Comment: @ChuckSavage Yea, I like your edits much better. Very clean. Hopefully this post will help somebody else trying to do similar functions; with multiple working solutions and options.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem with attempt #1 is that you are trying to compare an `IEnumerable<XElement>` to your reader value, this should work (assuming each bannerMain only has a single `filename` element):

```
var q = from node in doc.Descendants("bannerMain") 
        let fina = node.Element("filename")//only single filename, so get just that XElement
        where fina != null && fina.Value == reader[0]//assumes reader[0] is a string value
        select node;
```

To remove them just do this:

```
q.Remove();
doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/banners.xml"));
```

I ran this through LINQPad and after doing `q.Remove();`, here were the contents of doc: 
`<xml />`.

Comment: I'm sill having a problem. It's not making any changes to the xml file.

Comment: Thanks! I think that could have been the problem, going to go try things again!

Comment: ok it's still not quite there... for doc.Descendants("bannerMain") would I need to navigate to "xml/bannerMain" instead. xml being the all encompassing xml holder. (look at XML example above)

Comment: No, Descendants does not need any pathing, it looks throughout the Xml. I tested this using the xml snippet you posted and it worked fine with that. Is there a structure difference between your example Xml and the real one?

Comment: hmm, nope it's exactly the same.

Comment: And `reader[0]` is populated correctly? you may need to explicitly cast that to string before doing the comparison: `fina.Value == reader[0].ToString()`

Comment: Ok I got it working! I've already accepted the other answer but my problem was with the reader[0] not be a string. I converted it and everything cleared up. Thanks for working with me on this!

Answer (score 1):

It's a little verbose but here is a non-linq snippet:

```
void DeleteNode(string fileName)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/banners.xml"));

    //Get all the bannerMain nodes.
    XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("/xml//bannerMain");

    if (nodelist != null)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
        {
            //Look for then filename child. If it contains desired value
            //delete the entire bannerMain node. Assumes order of child nodes
            //may not be a constant.
            foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (child.Name == "filename" && child.InnerText == name)
                {
                    node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
                }
            }
        }

        doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/banners.xml"));
    }
}
```

Comment: (Just to clarify my understanding) the string 'fileName' you have set as the variable; that's the variable that I would be grabbing and setting from the SQL database correct??

Comment: Yep. You'd pass in whatever filename you'd like to find and delete.

Answer (score 1):

For Attempt #2, remove the @ sign for the filename.  The @ symbol represents an Attribute, but the filename is a child-node.

If your phrase doesn't work, I'd rephrase it a little from:

> "/xml/bannerMain[filename=

to

> "//bannerMain[filename=

Comment: I didn't realize the @ symbol was attribute related. Thanks for clarifying that. I'm going to try and make the edit and see if it fixes the problem with this option.